# print formatted multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to output my multi array in a nice format so i can read it easily

Here's my array code:

```
$weekly_array = array
    (
    "Sunday" =>     array(  "OT" => $sundayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $sundayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $sundayOT+$sundayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $sundaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 0),
    "Monday" =>     array(  "OT" => $mondayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $mondayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $mondayOT+$mondayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $mondaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 1),
    "Tuesday" =>    array(  "OT" => $tuesdayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $tuesdayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $tuesdayOT+$tuesdayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $tuesdaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 1),
    "Wednesday" =>  array(  "OT" => $wednesdayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $wednesdayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $wednesdayOT+$wednesdayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $wednesdaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 1),
    "Thursday" =>   array(  "OT" => $thursdayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $thursdayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $thursdayOT+$thursdayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $thursdaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 1),
    "Friday" =>     array(  "OT" => $fridayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $fridayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $fridayOT+$fridayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $fridaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 1),
    "Saturday" =>   array(  "OT" => $saturdayOT,
                            "LIEU" => $saturdayLIEU,
                            "TOTAL" => $saturdayOT+$saturdayLIEU,
                            "STAT" => $saturdaySTAT,
                            "WEEKDAY" => 0)
    );
```

Here's my code for output:

```
echo "<pre>" ;
echo "Day \t OT \t LIEU \t TOTAL \t STAT \t WEEKDAY";
array_map(function ($var) {
    echo "\n", $weekly_array[0], "\t", $var['OT'], "\t", $var['LIEU'], "\t", $var['TOTAL'], "\t", $var['STAT'], "\t", $var['WEEKDAY'];
}, $weekly_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Everything works but I can't get the week days to show (Sunday, Monday, etc...) - I tried `$weekly_array[0]` to display Sunday then Monday and so on for each line but it gives `error: Notice: Undefined variable: weekly_array`

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: Why not use `var_dump`?

Comment: `<pre><?php print_r($array); ?></pre>`

Comment: print_r function would be perfect ;)

Comment: PHP already has a functions [`print_r`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [`var_dump`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) which will output nice formats of arrays (and in the latter case, any variable).

Comment: array_map passes the array values to the callback, not the keys. your callback function will have no access to the keys. Since all you're doing is an echo anyways, and not MODIFYING the function, array_map is rather useless. do a conventional `foreach($arr as $key=>$var)` instead, then you can get the day names in `$key`

Comment: To fetch the array keys when using `array_map()`, see the first comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#81767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a standard `foreach` loop?

```
echo "<pre>" ;
echo "Day \t OT \t LIEU \t TOTAL \t STAT \t WEEKDAY";
foreach ($weekly_array as $key => $var) {
    echo "\n" .
    $key . "\t".
    $var['OT'] . "\t".
    $var['LIEU'] . "\t".
    $var['TOTAL'] . "\t".
    $var['STAT'] . "\t".
    $var['WEEKDAY'];
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop to iterate through the array, then display with html:

Example you could plug in.

```
foreach($weekly_array AS $value => $day) {
        echo "<strong>".$value."</strong><br>";
        foreach($day AS $key => $val){
            echo $key ." ".$val."</br>";
        }
       echo "<hr>";
    }
```